# Focus auto-advancing on dynamically added select elements

Tags: angular

I have a template that dynamically adds column headers with a select element(dropdown) in it, for each column in the dataset. The number of columns in the dataset is dynamic also. 
The issue I am seeing (I've only tested in Chrome and Edge), is that when you select a value in the first column, focus automatically switches to the next column's select, setting that next select to the same value I just selected in the previous. Change the value of the second, and focus switches to the third, with both the second and third having the same value. When I change the third, only the third is changed, so they are not all sharing the same model.

This happens if you are using the mouse or keyboard. With the keyboard it is more annoying because when you type the a letter, the first matching value is selected, and focus moves to the next select box, even if you wanted to get the second entry in the dropdown.

How do I get my dynamic generated column headers to NOT move to the next dropdown automatically?

Also, something a tiny more disturbing, when the focus is automatically switched to the next dropdown, the classes should be

> ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid

but they switch to

> ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid

so I dont thing validation is going to work.

I have a plunker to demonstrate [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/K0UI9PFlQPMGl9B249YV?p=preview)

here is the code:

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let curColumn of selectedColumnTypes;let colIndex = index">
            <td>
              <select name="ColumnType{{colIndex}}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedColumnTypes[colIndex]" required>
                <option *ngFor="let ct of colTypes" [value]="ct.Value">{{ct.Name}}</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let dataRow of sampleImport">
          <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let dataColumn of dataRow">{{dataColumn}}</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:lightgrey">
      Select boxes not tied to model<br/>
      <select name="test1" class="form-control" required>
        <option *ngFor="let ct of colTypes" [value]="ct.Value">{{ct.Name}}</option>
      </select>
      <select name="test2" class="form-control" required>
        <option *ngFor="let ct of colTypes" [value]="ct.Value">{{ct.Name}}</option>
      </select>
      <select name="test3" class="form-control" required>
        <option *ngFor="let ct of colTypes" [value]="ct.Value">{{ct.Name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  `,
})
export class App {
  selectedColumnTypes: Array<ColumnType> = new Array<ColumnType>();
  colTypes: Array<NameValuePair> = new Array<NameValuePair>();
  sampleImport:Array<any[]> = new Array<any[]>();
  constructor() {
    //three of these because we have three columns (this number is dynamic in actual code)
    this.selectedColumnTypes.push(null);
    this.selectedColumnTypes.push(null);
    this.selectedColumnTypes.push(null);

    this.colTypes.push(new NameValuePair("Faculty", ColumnType.Faculty));
    this.colTypes.push(new NameValuePair("First Name", ColumnType.FirstName));
    this.colTypes.push(new NameValuePair("Last Name", ColumnType.LastName));
    this.colTypes.push(new NameValuePair("Email", ColumnType.Email));
    this.colTypes.push(new NameValuePair("Phone", ColumnType.Phone));

    this.sampleImport.push(["a@b.com","James" , "Smith"   ]);
    this.sampleImport.push(["e@f.com","Rick"  , "Jones"   ]);
    this.sampleImport.push(["g@f.com","Oscar" , "Taylor"  ]);
    this.sampleImport.push(["h@f.com","Taylor", "Williams"]);
    this.sampleImport.push(["d@f.com","John"  , "Doe"     ]);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}

export enum ColumnType {
    FistName =1,
    LastName = 2,
    Email = 3,
    Phone = 4,
    Faculty = 5
}

export class NameValuePair {
  constructor(
    public Name: string,
    public Value: any
  ) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but ngModel on [(ngModel)]="selectedColumnTypes[colIndex]" is causing you issues.  I was able to fix it by giving each selectedColumnTypes a unique object.

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedColumnTypes[colIndex].index"


this.selectedColumnTypes.push({ index: null});
this.selectedColumnTypes.push({ index: null});
this.selectedColumnTypes.push({ index: null});
```

Here's the updated working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/cNge2aA1aQsAr9YI338j?p=preview

Comment: Thx! Based on your answer, it seems ngModel has quirks with references, via an array, to primitives.